# Handle refresh token and failed requests retry when access token expires in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to implement an OAuth authentication mechanism with refresh token and access token. I have searched for the solution a lot. But, still I haven't find any comprehensive solution that works for me.
I have different watchers for different actions. The main problem is when the access token expires. I want to have a solution for refreshing the token and more importantly re-try failed request with 401 code. What is the best solution for my case? I don't want to miss any failed request and want to retry them all.

Comment: What have you tried and what was your problem?

Comment: @AmrMostafa I have no idea how and where to implement it. In redux-saga, redux itself. Where to save my failed request containing request data

Comment: My advise is to take it a step by step, start by making your API requests go through redux-saga without any of the additional stuff you mention, there are many examples online for that. Then add features one by one and ask questions when you have something going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that I should handle it in axios level. Saga waits for the request to be resolved and there is no need to be aware what happens in request level.